# Why doesn't the 1 dimensional ising model have a transition temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-spin, ising-model

Consider a 1 dimensional chain of spins that are able to either have the value $\sigma =$ $+1$, $-1$, from now on referred to as up and down. For the Hamiltonian $H = J \sum_{i,j} \sigma_i \sigma_j$ the ground state is clearly when all spins are aligned (if J < 0). Consider now a kink in the chain. For example for N=6 spins, having 3 up-spins followed by 3-down spins is ONE kink.

The change in free energy due to one kink is given by $F = U - TS = |J| - k_B T ln(N)$. In my textbook it says that this clearly is never bigger or equal zero for arbitrary $T>0$, which would make kinks energetically unfavourable and thus preserve the ferromagnetic ground state. I don't really see why this is never bigger than zero though. For $ T = |J| / k_B ln N$ the free energy change is zero. So since the function is continuous there should be lots of temperature at which the free energy change isn't negative, right? I feel like I'm missing something completely obvious and hope you can help me.

Cheers!

Comment: Phase transitions (in the sense of nonanalyticities of thermodynamic potentials) can only exist in the thermodynamic limit. So, you have to fix $T>0$ and consider what happens in the limit $N\to\infty$. Note also that, for any finite $N$, typical samples will be perfectly ordered (i.e., magnetization equal to $1$) with very high probability provided you take the temperature sufficiently low, but this is just a finite-size effect, which disappears in the thermodynamic limit.

Comment: I don't think that argument is mathematically sound. N isn't strictly going to infinity, it's in the order of $10^{23}$ or one mole. The Boltzmann constant is of the same order of magnitude, making the $N \rightarrow \inf$ an unvalid approximation, I think.

Comment: I can guarantee you that it is perfectly sound. Just look at your free energy: at finite $N$, it is an analytic function of the temperature (more generally, the partition function is just a polynomial in $e^{-\beta}$ with nonnegative real coefficients, so its logarithm is real-analytic)! The only way you can generate non-analyticities is in the thermodynamic limit. This is a general fact. Of course, "real" phase transitions (i.e., for infinite systems) are well approximated by the behavior of large finite systems, which is why you can observe (apparent) singular behavior in finite systems too.

Comment: You might also have a look at Figure 1.11 in this [book in progress](http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook/index.html). It shows the behavior of the magnetization in the 2d Ising model for increasing system sizes (including the infinite system). You can see that the curve is smooth for finite systems, but nevertheless approximate better and better the non-smooth one you get in the thermodynamic limit. BTW, the one-dimensional Ising model is discussed there in Section 3.3.

Comment: I should also mention that a precise discussion of the relation between the local behavior of finite and infinite two-dimensional Ising models is given in Section 3.8.6. It requires some terminology, but the latter is explained earlier in the chapter.